# Third order differential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the problem below:
Given the equation $$y'''(x)+p(x)y''(x)+q(x)y'(x)+r(x)y(x)=0 $$with $p(x),q(x),r(x)$ belong to $\mathbb {R}$ and $y_1(x),y_2(x)$ two linear independent of the equation and $[y_2(x)/y_1(x)]≠0$ and $y_1(x)≠0$.

Show that $z=[y_2(x)/y_1(x)]'$ is the solution of the second order equation that resulting from reducing the order and the use of the solution $y_1(x)$

I have stucked and don't know to go further

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: First step: write $y = y_1 \int z \, \mathrm{d}x$ with the known solution $y_1$, and use the product rule to obtain a second-order linear ODE for $z$.